# Textboxes always filled in the browsers

Tags: asp.net, textbox, autofill

In my recent projects, two textboxes in pages  Register and Edit. Always returns the login pages value which has UserName & password.
However I disabled the autocomplete property. but it still the same.

you can see it in this picture.

[image]

Here are the codes for both textboxes:
Emailtextbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail"  CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Email" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter A Valid Email Address( example@example.com )"
ControlToValidate="txtEmail1" CssClass="requiredFieldValidateStyle"  ForeColor="Red"ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" />
```

Password Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword"  CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Password" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExp1" runat="server"    
ErrorMessage="Password length must be between 7 to 15 characters(character ', _ is not allowed!)"
ControlToValidate="txtPassword"  
 ForeColor="Red"  
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9@#*.\s]{7,15}$" SetFocusOnError="True"/>
```

This issue is the same in all browsers (IE, Chrome and Firefox). Any Ideas?